# VBA - Accessing Text Value Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code:

```
Function Find_Index(Gender As String)

   Dim Index As Long

   Do While Gender = Worksheets("Source").Cells(Index, "A").Text

       Index = Index + 1

   Loop

   Find_Index = Index

End Function
```

I'm getting the following error:

"Application-defined or object-defined error"

Due to the following line in the code:

```
Do While Gender = Worksheets("Source").Cells(Index, "A").Text
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `Index` but never set it to a value before you use it.

Add `Index = 1` before the `Do While` line

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you very much!